# Or and not equal

Tags: c++

Why does this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s="a";
if((s=="cm")||(s=="in")||(s=="ft")||(s=="m"))
        cout<<s+" Is an illegal value";
else
        cout<<"I like "+s;
        return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/7pnYh

but then this doesnt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s="a";
if((s!="cm")||(s!="in")||(s!="ft")||(s!="m"))
        cout<<s+" Is an illegal value";
else
        cout<<"I like "+s;
        return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/TXUXA
The answer i want for both is "I like a" .

Comment: Why would you expect the second to give "I like a"? Just trace it: Does "a" != "cm"? yes. Does "a" != "in"? yes. Does "a" != "ft"? yes. Does "a" != "m"? yes. Does (s!="cm") or (s!="in") or (s!="ft") or (s!="m")? yes.

Comment: How embarrassing, youre right i shouldnt expect "I like a", thanks for the answers everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second case `s != "cm"` and of course the first `cout` is printed. To negate the check and the logic to remain the same, do it like this:

```
if((s!="cm")&&(s!="in")&&(s!="ft")&&(s!="m"))
        cout<<"I like "+s;
else
        cout<<s+" Is an illegal value";
```

Answer (score 3):

More specifically, you didn't apply `De Morgan's law` correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Answer (score 1):

```
(s!="cm")||(s!="in")||(s!="ft")||(s!="m")
```

Each and everyone of those is true, so clearly the expression is true.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the second one output "I like a"?
Every single one of your conditions in the statement in the second example is true, so it goes into the if branch. Even if only one would be true, it still would go into the if branch, because you are using OR.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to check whether it's unequal to *all* of those strings, not whether it's unequal to *any* of those strings.

Use **and**, not **or**.

Comment: Correct, but also he has to swap the `couts`.

Comment: He isn't, he expects it to evaluate to false. Maybe if(!((s!="cm")&&(s!="in")&&(s!="ft")&&(s!="m"))) is what he is trying to do?

Comment: @ssteinberg - I think so. Either add an additional `!` or swap the `couts`.

Answer (score 1):

Negation changes the logic behind it. There's more theory here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation but basically, in the second example, you want to check that none of the conditions match - meaning you'd have to have && (and) operator instead of || (or)